# Given an excel table we have to find sum of Points correponding to top 3(in magnitude) scores?

Tags: excel

***Table Image:***

[image]

What I have tried:

```
{=SUM(VLOOKUP(LARGE(B2:B14,{1;2;3}),B1:C14,2,0))}
```

This query is only giving me the "Points" value corresponding to "first highest score".

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? `Excel365` can be easier to achieve your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS()` with `LARGE()`.

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C14,B2:B14,">=" & LARGE(B2:B14,3))
```

[image]

Comment: @ujjwal_bansal Glad to know! Then please mark it as answered (Tick mark it).